# How do i create a method/function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i create a method in Jquery

For example

```
function dosomething()
{
 // do something 
}
dosomething();// i can call the function this way
```

How can i define function like dosomething() and call them in jquery?

Thanks

Comment: you need a jquery plugin or a normal JS function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In exactly the same way.  jQuery *is* JavaScript.

```
function doSomething() {
    // do something
}
$(function () {
    doSomething(); // call doSomething on document ready.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a basic jQuery function:

```
(function($)
{
  $.fn.myFunc = function()
  {
    return this.each(function()
    {
      alert("do something for each element return by JQuery object");
    });
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Doing the above allows me to `$("#myElement").myFunc();`

Don't forget that jQuery *is* javascript. Javascript *is not* jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on [jQuery plugin authoring here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)